# Map laziness in clojure

Tags: swing, dictionary, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I am building a simple swing GUI in Clojure. I am trying to apply a single function to multiple GUI components by using map in the context of a let:

`(map #(f % component4) [component1 component2 component3])`

Where the components are all defined in the let.

Problematically, map is lazy, and the action is not applied to the components, however, I can force it by wrapping the above in a 'take'.

Is there a non lazy alternative to map? Or should I be going about this differently?

EDIT:
Using counterclockwise in eclipse. I had different results using (use 'Lib :reload) from the REPL and using CTRL+Enter from the editor. Reloading would launch the GUI, but the problem described above would occur. The problem did not occur when using CTRL+Enter from the editor, therefore I think my description of the problem may be inaccurate. Regardless, doseq seems to be a better alternative to map in this scenario.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I challenge your assertion that getting `take` involved makes any difference at all. If you wrapped it in `doall` or `dorun` it would do what you want, but you should consider using `doseq` instead of `map` for this sort of side-effect-only action.

### Note

Originally posted as comment on question; copied to answer by popular demand.

Comment: I don't follow. If you take all the elements, don't you force realization of them? I'm not arguing that doall etc isn't better, but presumably take 3 would also work?

Comment: Ah! I never knew that, but indeed:
(first (take 10000 (map #(do (Thread/sleep 10) %) (range))))
returns very quickly.

Comment: @AdrianMouat It actually realizes 32 elements, because range and map are both chunked for efficiency - so it takes 0.32 seconds. But `(first (take 10000 (map #(do (Thread/sleep 10) %) (repeat 1))))` does return in 0.01 seconds as expected.

Comment: I did wonder why it timed out (on tryclj.com) with higher values for sleep. Thanks, I've learned a lot this morning :)

Answer (score 8):

**[doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq)** is probably the best way to approach this. doseq is roughly equivalent to a "for-each" statement that loops over each element of a collection in many other languages. It is guaranteed to be non-lazy.

```
(doseq 
  [comp [component1 component2 component3]]
  (f comp component4))
```

Some general advice:

- Use **map** and its lazy friends (including take, drop etc.) when you want a *sequence as an output*
- Use **doseq**, **doall**, **dotimes** etc. when you are more interested in the side effects

Comment: Rule of thumb: Side-effects? Look for `do` in the name.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping your map in a doall will force its evaluation. or a better alternative is doseq which is used for things involving side effects.

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely. The syntax also works better for what I was trying to do.